# Evaluating Performance Affects of User Analytics

Tags: javascript, performance, web, analytics

I am planning to include a user analytics tool - most likely Clicky to my site.

What worries me is the performance effect it might have on the whole site. It is loaded just before the body tag ends:

```
<noscript><p><img alt="Clicky" width="1" height="1" src="//in.getclicky.com/100874070ns.gif" /></p></noscript>
<script type="text/javascript" src="clicky.js"></script>
</body>
</html>`
```

I already evaluated the JS loading time of the solution, which seems to load the script about 2 seconds. **As I understand this wouldn't harm the actual page usage, but am I right?**

1) Does the js start to log events only after it's loaded (let's say 2 seconds)?

2) Are there any other ways of estimating the script load then the *network* section's load time in chrome inspector (or similar tool)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes - it can't log anything, unless it attaches an event handler,
   and for that it needs to be loaded.
2. There many [online tools](http://www.smashingapps.com/2012/02/14/15-excellent-tools-for-profiling-your-websites-speed.html), to profile web performance. In the
   (far) past I've used [WebPagetest](http://www.webpagetest.org/), which helped me a lot, but I don't really no what is the best tool nowdays.

Suggestion - Try to use [async or defer](http://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2014/02/async-vs-defer-attributes.html) attributes on the `<script>` tag, and see if it makes a difference.